# Roots of a complex number, solutions

Tags: complex-analysis

I have to find the roots of this complex number.

$z^6-\frac{1-2i}{2-i}=0$

I simplified:

$z=\sqrt[6]{\frac{4}{5}-\frac{3}{5}i}$

Are the solutions these?

$z=\cos{\frac{\arctan{\frac{3}{4}}+2kπ}{6}+i\sin{\frac{\arctan{\frac{3}{4}}+2kπ}{6}}}$

(For k=0,1,2,3,4,5)

Comment: it seems correct but i think it should be $\arctan(-\frac34)$ instead as the given complex number lies in the fourth quadrant